# position arc relative to circle

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, circles, arc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/draw-arc-in-tikz-when-center-of-circle-is-specified)

an very trivial question but I can't do it! Sorry but I find coordinates confusing.

I would like to draw an arc around a circle; both should have the same center of rotation. And I want to position the arc relative to the circle.

Here is the MWE to correct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=4em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, fill=black!20] (sh1) at (1,3) {Circle};
\draw[thick] (sh1) arc (0:300:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

How do I get to have the same center for both shapes, with relative positioning of the arc? Any simple and brilliant idea?

Comment: You can replace your `\draw ...` command with `\draw[thick] (sh1) ++(0:2cm) arc (0:300:2cm);` to move to a point on the circle before drawing the arc. See Leo Liu's answer to [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66219/2552)

Comment: Thanks Jake. I did have a look at the post you mention before posting mine but I could not make the code work. I am not familiar with this way of coding.

Comment: No problem. It's always a good idea to include the things you've tried and the questions you've already looked at in your question. That way, people will be able to offer more specific advice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that for `arc` you specify the start point of the arc, not the cirle's center. You could define a custom command like this:

### The Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=4em}}

\def\centerarc[#1] (#2) (#3:#4:#5)% [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
{ \draw[#1] (#2) ++(#3:#5) arc (#3:#4:#5);
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[state, fill=black!20] (sh1) at (1,3) {Circle};
\centerarc[thick] (sh1) (0:300:2cm)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Special thanks to **Paul Gaborit** and **Jake** for simplifying this.

### The Result

[image]

Comment: To specify the start point, the following notation is simpler: `($(#2) + (#3:#5)$)`...

Comment: @Jake, thanks, just saw that, I will update.

Comment: Well, just great!

Answer (score 4):

Well, I don't a have brilliant idea ... but note, that `arc` always starts at given coordinate - in your case at the center of the circle `sh1`, and its center is shifted by the amount specified in last argument for `arc` - in your case by 2cm. So, if you shift the start of the `arc` in the appropriate direction and amount, you will get what you desired (if I understand your problem correctly).

In your case try:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\tikzset{state/.style={circle,draw=black, very thick,minimum size=4em}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[help lines] (-3,-3) grid + (9,9);
\node[state, fill=black!20] (sh1) at (1,3) {Circle};
\draw[thick] ([xshift=20mm] sh1.center) arc (0:300:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Zarko. It works well. The only (minimal) issue I see is that if I change the angles in the arc, the arc and the circle do not share automatically the same center of rotation. But this can be remedied. Thanks again.