# Using \tikzfillbetween to color between two curves

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm having trouble filling a region between two curves.
I would prefer to work in tikz rather than overlay pgfplots.
Here is what I've tried:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{ insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)} } }
\draw [name path=A] (5,8) [partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
\draw[name path=B] (5,0) [partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{blue, opacity=0.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But for some strange reason, it only work on the right side of the figure, and on the left it fills up to a horizontal line, instead of between.

[image]

Comment: Hint: You could use the (complex) solution here (redefinition of drawing arcs): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123189/124842. And then `\draw[green,name path=A]   (0,2) arc [start angle=180,   end angle=360];\draw[green,name path=B]   (0,0) arc [start angle=180,   end angle=360];
  \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{blue, opacity=0.1};`. You need àlso the packages `\usepackage{pgfplots}` and 
`\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob, please convert your comment to answer!

Comment: @Zarko i added the workaround answer. But i can't add more information why this works. I'm not an expert.  This exceeds my capacity. Sorry. Iif you (or someone else, maybe @Qrrbrbirlbel) could add some explanation, feel free to edit my answer... . Also i think the OP is still open.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part [of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 9):

*A workaround:* If you [redefine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123189/124842) (the way TikZ draws its arc) from @Qrrbrbirlbel, you could fill the region between two curves with:

```
\draw[green,name path=A]   (0,2) arc [start angle=180,   end angle=360];
\draw[green,name path=B]   (0,0) arc [start angle=180,   end angle=360];
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{blue, opacity=0.2};
```

Length and radius are defined with `x radius=6` and  `y radius=1.5`.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\makeatletter
\def\tikz@arc@opt[#1]{% over-write!
  {%
    \tikzset{every arc/.try,#1}%
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/start angle}\tikz@s
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/end angle}\tikz@e
    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/delta angle}\tikz@d
    \ifx\tikz@s\pgfutil@empty%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@s{\tikz@e-\tikz@d}
    \else
      \ifx\tikz@e\pgfutil@empty%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\tikz@e{\tikz@s+\tikz@d}
      \fi%
    \fi
    \tikz@arc@moveto
    \xdef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand%
    \tikz@do@arc{\tikz@s}{\tikz@e}
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}}
      {\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}}}%
  }%
  \pgf@marshal%
  \tikz@arcfinal%
}
\let\tikz@arc@moveto\relax
\def\tikz@arc@movetolineto#1{%
  \def\tikz@arc@moveto{\tikz@@@parse@polar{\tikz@arc@@movetolineto#1}(\tikz@s:\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius} and \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius})}}
\def\tikz@arc@@movetolineto#1#2{#1{\pgfpointadd{#2}{\tikz@last@position@saved}}}
\tikzset{%
  move to start/.code=\tikz@arc@movetolineto\pgfpathmoveto,%
  line to start/.code=\tikz@arc@movetolineto\pgfpathlineto}
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x radius=6, y radius=1.5]
  \draw[green,name path=A]   (0,2) arc [start angle=180,   end angle=360];
  \draw[green,name path=B]   (0,0) arc [start angle=180,   end angle=360];
  \tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{blue, opacity=0.2};
%\tikzset{partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{ insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)} } }
%\draw [name path=AA,red] (6,0) [partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
%\draw [name path=BB,red] (6,2) [partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
%\tikzfillbetween[of=AA and BB]{red, opacity=0.1};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The line from `(5,8)` to the starting point of the partial ellipse is not drawn but part of path `A`. The same happens for `(5,0)` and `B`.

Maybe you can use `(5,8)` and `(5,0)` as values of option `shift`. Then the starting point of the path is the same as the starting point of the drawn partial ellipse:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% to avoid the pgfplots warning
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
\tikzset{partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{ insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)} } }
\draw[name path=A, shift={(5,8)}, partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
\draw[name path=B, shift={(5,0)}, partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{blue, opacity=0.1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Additional remark regarding a comment below:

You could also fill the region using patterns:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads also tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}% to avoid the pgfplots warning
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, pgfplots.fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}% <- added
\pgfdeclarelayer{pre main}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfsetlayers{pre main,main}
\tikzset{partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{ insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)} } }
\draw[name path=A, shift={(5,8)}, partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
\draw[name path=B, shift={(5,0)}, partial ellipse=180:360:6cm and 1.5cm];
\tikzfillbetween[of=A and B]{pattern=vertical lines, pattern color=red!50!black};% <- changed
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to modify your code to fill the same region with `patterns`?

Comment: @SubhajitPaul See the new example at the end of my answer..