# TikZ: ellipse-arcs around a center-point with start- and end-angle

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc, ellipse

[image]

**Problem in short: The ellipse-arc should lie around Z and should start and end at the brown lines...**

---

I want to draw circle-arcs  and ellipse-arcs around a center-point.

So I use the syntax (*TikZ-manual 2.10, page 36*)

```
\draw[]([shift=(\wStart:\r)]Z) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\r];
```

with defined values `\wStart`, `\wEnd`, `\r` and a middlepoint-coordinate `Z` (which is not necessarily `(0,0)`)  for circle-arcs and this works

For **ellipse-arcs** I use the syntax written in the *TikZ-manual 2.10, page 37*

```
\draw[red] ([shift=(\wStart:\rx)]Z) arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];
```

in the following MWE.

*But it seems my "center-shift" is wrong or it does not work* (and maybe (?) start- and end-angle seems to be not correct).

What do I have to do?

BTW: *I saw [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123187/46023) (do not get the correct result with his methode), but I would like to fix the TikZ-syntax.*

[image]

**The ellipse-arc should start and end at the brown lines...**

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
% Center
\coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (0,0);
\fill[] (Z) circle[radius=2pt];

% Values ===============
\def\rx{1.75}
\def\ry{1}

\def\r{\rx}

\def\wStart{20}
\def\wEnd{315}
% ====================

% Help lines
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (\wStart:\r);
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (\wEnd:\r);

% Full circle and ellipse
\draw[] (Z) circle[radius=\r];
\draw[] (Z) circle[x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];

% cirlce arc
\draw[blue] ([shift=(\wStart:\r)]Z) arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\r] node[near start]{good};

% ellipse arc
\draw[red] ([shift=(\wStart:\rx)]Z) arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry] node[near start]{bad};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: A point `(α:rx and ry)` isn't on the line from the origin to `(α:Rx)`. You're going to have to find the point and the angle mathematically or let `intersections`/`spath3` find it for you.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I see. Would be nice to use the original TikZ-syntax with some needed math-inputs. But I tried many calculations, and I don't get the correct.  So I was using a 'plot' with standard-formulas for the first (in my answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For another approach, you can apply a scale, draw an arc and compute the new angles:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\myscale{\ry/\rx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStartE{atan(tan(\wStart)/\myscale)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEndE{360+atan(tan(\wEnd)/\myscale)}
```

A complete example could be:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
% Center
\coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (0,0);
\fill[] (Z) circle[radius=2pt];

% Values ===============
\def\rx{1.75}
\def\ry{1}
\def\r{\rx}
\def\wStart{20}
\def\wEnd{315}

% Scale and new angles
\pgfmathsetmacro\myscale{\ry/\rx}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wStartE{atan(tan(\wStart)/\myscale)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\wEndE{360+atan(tan(\wEnd)/\myscale)}
% ====================

% Help lines
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (\wStart:\r);
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (\wEnd:\r);

% Full circle and ellipse
\draw[] (Z) circle[radius=\r];
\draw[] (Z) circle[x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];

% cirlce arc
\draw[blue] ([shift=(\wStart:\r)]Z) arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\r] node[near start]{good};

% ellipse arc
\draw[red,yscale=\myscale] ([shift=(\wStartE:\r)]Z) arc [start angle=\wStartE, end angle=\wEndE, radius=\r] node[near start]{good?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, “good” :()  I think this is the solution in terms of the task.

Comment: Instead of `yscale` one  should also be able to use `x radius` and `y radius`. But phew: my head is spinning right now.

Answer (score 6):

With `tkz-elements` requires compilation with `lualatex`

Edit: With Qrrbrbirlbel's comment, I use the clip that adapts to the situation

Edit2: With Alain Matthes'comment, we can read in the `tkz-elements` documentation:

> set_lua_to_tex.  You need to proceed with care, because unfortunately at the moment, the macros you create are global and you can overwrite existing macros. One solution is
> either to choose a macro name that won’t cause any problems, or to
> save the initial macro.

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tkzelements}
    rx = value(1.75)
    ry = value(1)
    wStart = 20
    wEnd = 315
    z.Z = point: new (0 , 0)
    z.A = point: new (0 , rx)-- to draw the circle
    --
    c = circle : new (z.Z,z.A)
    e = ellipse: radii (z.Z,rx,ry,0)
    -- 
    z.Sp = point : polar_deg(rx,wStart)
    L.ZSp = line : new ( z.Z , z.Sp )
    if wStart <180 then
        z.S,_ = intersection (e,L.ZSp)--  Start point
    else
        _,z.S = intersection (e,L.ZSp)
    end
    --  
    z.Ep = point : polar_deg(rx,wEnd)
    L.ZEp = line : new ( z.Z , z.Ep )
    if wEnd <180 then
        z.E,_ = intersection (e,L.ZEp)--  End point
    else
        _,z.E = intersection (e,L.ZEp)
    end
    --
    -- set_lua_to_tex{"rx","ry","wStart","wEnd"}-- see Alain Matthes'comment
\end{tkzelements}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
    % Edit2
    \newcommand{\rx}{\tkzUseLua{rx}}
    \newcommand{\ry}{\tkzUseLua{ry}}
    \newcommand{\wStart}{\tkzUseLua{wStart}}
    \newcommand{\wEnd}{\tkzUseLua{wEnd}}
    %
    \tkzGetNodes
    \tkzDrawPoints(Z,S,S',E,E')
    \tkzLabelPoints(Z)
    \tkzDrawCircle[blue](Z,A)
    %\draw[green!70!black] (Z) -- +(\wStart:2*\rx) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=2*\rx] -- cycle;
    \begin{scope}
        % With Qrrbrbirlbel's comment
        \clip [overlay](Z) -- +(\wStart:2*\rx) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=2*\rx] -- cycle;
        %
        \tkzDrawEllipse[red](Z,\rx,\ry,0)
    \end{scope}
    \tkzDrawSegments[brown](S,Z Z,E)
    \tkzDrawSegments[brown,dashed](S,S' E,E')
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I prefer  \tkzDrawEllipse[red](Z,\tkzUseLua{rx},\tkzUseLua{ry},0)  or even  `\def\rx{\tkzUseLua{rx}}` etc.   because set_lua_to_tex creates global macros. Good use of the package !

Comment: @Alain Matthes, I promise to read the documentation better. A little in advance, Happy New Year!

Answer (score 4):

I fear, this could become a hard work, to "hack the TikZ-ellipse", so I used
[*Polar form relative to center*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center) and then a `plot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded,
]
% Values ===============
\def\rx{1.75}
\def\ry{1}

\def\r{\rx}

\def\wStart{20}
\def\wEnd{315}
% ====================

% Center
\coordinate[label=below:{(0,0)}] (O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (1.3,2);
\foreach \P in {O,Z} \fill[] (\P) circle[radius=2pt];

% Help lines
\draw[brown] (Z) -- +(\wStart:\r);
\draw[brown] (Z) -- +(\wEnd:\r);

% Full circle and ellipse
\draw[] (Z) circle[radius=\r];
\draw[] (Z) ellipse[x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];

% circle arc
\draw[blue] ([shift=(\wStart:\rx)]Z)  arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\r];

% ellipse arc
\tikzset{% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Polar_form_relative_to_center
declare function={
E=sqrt(\rx^2-\ry^2)/\rx;
PolarEllipse(\x)=\ry/sqrt(1-E^2*cos(\x)^2);   },       }%

\draw[red, very thick,
domain=\wStart:\wEnd,
samples=111
] plot ([shift={(Z)}]\x:{PolarEllipse(\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I like value-keys over macros but essentially, this uses the PGFMath function `ellAngle` to find the angle for the ellipse function while a few other PGFMath functions are used that simply map to a value-key. The functions `maxRadius` and `minRadius` evaluate the value-keys `x radius` and `y radius`.

This means the arcs can be drawn via

```
\begin{scope}[shift=(Z)]
\draw[green] (sAngle:maxRadius) arc [big   circle];
\draw[blue]  (sAngle:minRadius) arc [small circle];
\draw[red]   (ellAngle sAngle:xRadius and yRadius)
              arc [start angle ell, end angle ell];
\end{scope}
```

Applying `shift=(Z)` before the paths allows us to remove the `shift` operations from the paths making the input somewhat cleaner. (`\draw[shift=(Z), …] …;` would work, too.)

The keys `small circle` and `big circle` install `minRadius` and `maxRadius` while `start angle ell` and `end angle ell` apply the `ellAngle` function on their parameters (which default to the value-keys `start angle` and `end angle`).

---

With [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123189) to [TikZ: using the ellipse command with a start and end angle instead of an arc](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/123158) this can be written as

```
\begin{scope}[shift=(Z), arc starts=after moveto]
\draw[green] arc [big   circle];
\draw[blue]  arc [small circle];
\draw[red]   arc [start angle ell, end angle ell];
\end{scope}
```

removing the need for `sAngle`.

I'm also using the `bbox` library and its `bezier bounding box` key to get accurate bounding boxes for the arcs.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds, bbox}
\tikzset{
  big   circle/.style={radius/.evaluated=maxRadius},
  small circle/.style={radius/.evaluated=minRadius},
  declare function={
    ellAngle(\x)=atan(xRadius/yRadius*tan(\x))+ellAngleCorr(mod(\x,360));
    ellAngleCorr(\x)=ifthenelse(\x>270,360,ifthenelse(\x>90,180,0));},
  start angle ell/.style={start angle/.expanded={ellAngle(#1)}}, start angle ell/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/start angle},
  end   angle ell/.style={end   angle/.expanded={ellAngle(#1)}}, end   angle ell/.default=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/end   angle},
  @/.code args={#1>#2}{\pgfmathdeclarefunction{#1}{0}{\pgfmathparse{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/#2}}}},
  @/.list={xRadius>x radius, yRadius>y radius, sAngle>start angle, eAngle>end angle}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{maxRadius}{0}{\pgfmathmax{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}}}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{minRadius}{0}{\pgfmathmin{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x radius}}{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/y radius}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  gridded,
  x radius=1.75, y radius=1, start angle=20, end angle=315]
% Center
\coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (0,0);
\fill[] (Z) circle[radius=2pt];

% Help lines
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (sAngle:maxRadius);
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (eAngle:maxRadius);

% Full circle and ellipse
\draw[] (Z) circle[big circle];
\draw[] (Z) circle[];
\draw[] (Z) circle[small circle];

% Arcs
\begin{scope}[shift=(Z), bezier bounding box]
\draw[green] (sAngle:maxRadius) arc [big   circle];
\draw[blue]  (sAngle:minRadius) arc [small circle];
\draw[red]   (ellAngle sAngle:xRadius and yRadius)
              arc [start angle ell, end angle ell];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: `ellAngle(90)` and `ellAngle(270)` will fail with an error, of course, but for those angles, the function isn't needed (nor is it for 0° and 180°).

Answer (score 4):

Just for fun:  This uses cicles and ellipses and clips the part not wanted.  Note the use of `-| (\r,0) |-` to extend the clipped area to the border.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
% Center
\coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (0,0);
\fill[] (Z) circle[radius=2pt];

% Values ===============
\def\rx{1.75}
\def\ry{1}

\def\r{\rx}

\def\wStart{20}
\def\wEnd{315}
% ====================

% Help lines
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (\wStart:\r);
\draw[brown] (Z) -- (\wEnd:\r);

% Full circle and ellipse
\draw[] (Z) circle[radius=\r];
\draw[] (Z) circle[x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];

% cirlce arc
\begin{scope}[even odd rule]
\clip (-\r,-\r) rectangle (\r,\r)% clip exterior
  (\wStart:2) -- (Z) -- (\wEnd:2) -| (\r,0) |- cycle;% clip interior
\draw[blue] (Z) circle [radius=\r];

% ellipse arc
\draw[red] (Z) ellipse [x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, let the PDF viewer do the math! Though, just clipping the arc seems easier: `\clip[overlay] (Z) -- +(\wStart:2*\r) arc[start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=2*\r] -- cycle;`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the arc operation doesn't work always as one would expect, see Ch. "14.7 The Arc Operation". To further complicate things your end points weren't always right, which you can see when varying the Z-coordinate.

Here's a way to do it, using [Jake's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123187/245790), who introduced a partial ellipse. The problem is that the starting point of your arc lies on an ellipse, not on a circle, which shifts it, upwards in this case.

The angles (brown lines) are fine for multiples of 90deg, and not right else, so there's a residual problem to solve.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}
 \tikzset{
    partial ellipse/.style args={#1:#2:#3}{
        insert path={+ (#1:#3) arc (#1:#2:#3)}
    }
 }
 \begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
    % Center
    \coordinate[label=below:Z] (Z) at (10,0);% <<< let's play with this
    \fill[] (Z) circle[radius=2pt];
    
    % Values ===============
    \def\rx{1.75}
    \def\ry{1}
    
    \def\r{\rx}
    
    % ~~~ needed for partial ellipse ~~~
    \def\ell{1.75cm and 1cm}
    
    \def\wStart{20}
    \def\wEnd{315}
    % ====================
    
    % Help lines
    % !!! wrong end points ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    \draw[brown] (Z) -- ([shift=(\wStart:\r)]Z);%(\wStart:\r);
    \draw[brown] (Z) -- ([shift=(\wEnd:\r)]Z);%(\wEnd:\r);
    
    % Full circle and ellipse
    \draw[]       (Z) circle[radius=\r];
    \draw[dashed] (Z) circle[x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry];
    
    % cirlce arc
    \draw[blue] ([shift=(\wStart:\r)]Z) arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, radius=\r] node[near start]{good};
    
    %   % ellipse arc --- this leads to nothing
    %   \draw[red] ([shift=(0:\rx)]Z) 
    %%      arc [start angle=\wStart, end angle=\wEnd, x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry]
    %       arc [start angle=30, delta angle=180,x radius=\rx, y radius=\ry]
    %       node[near start]{bad};

    % partial ellipse
    % found at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123187/245790
    \draw[red] (Z) [partial ellipse=\wStart:\wEnd:\ell];
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you say me: there is no way? Because: the ellipse-arc should start and end at the brown lines... and you haven't got that too.  Mmmmhh... I think the angles have to be corrected (by a pgfmath-term); but I am not sure...

Comment: No, there is certainly a way, but in a region, I've never investigated before. I suggest searching this site a little bit more than I did.

Answer (score 1):

[`tzplot`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tzplot) translation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tzplot}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[gridded]
% Center
\tzcoor(0,0)(Z){Z}[b]
\tzdot*(Z)(4pt)

% Values ===============
\def\rx{1.75}
\def\ry{1}
\def\r{\rx}
\def\wStart{20}
\def\wEnd{315}
% ====================

% Help lines
\tzline[brown](Z)(\wStart:\r)
\tzline[brown](Z)(\wEnd:\r)

% Full circle and ellipse
\tzcircle(Z)(\r)
\tzcircle(Z)({\rx} and {\ry})

% cirlce arc
\tzarc[blue](Z)(\wStart:\wEnd:\r){good}[near start]

% ellipse arc
\pgfmathsetmacro\XwStart{atan(tan(\wStart)*(\rx/\ry))} % scaled angle
\pgfmathsetmacro\XwEnd{atan(tan(\wEnd)*(\rx/\ry))+360} % scaled angle
\tzarc[red](Z)(\XwStart:\XwEnd:{\rx} and {\ry}){bad?}[near start]
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```