# Undefined control sequence \tkzDrawArc

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

I'm trying to follow an example of arc drawing from one [tex.stackexchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66438/36381) question:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,-2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(60:2){B}
    \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and .5](O,A O,B)
    \tkzDrawArc[rotate,color=red](O,A)(180)
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

And I keep getting this error message

```
Undefined control sequence.
\tkzDrawArc
[rotate,color=red](O,A)(180)
?
```

I'm using the following packages:

```
\usepackage{fullpage,amsfonts,amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{yhmath}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably you are missing

```
\usetkzobj{all}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(2,-2){A}
    \tkzDefPoint(60:2){B}
    \tkzDrawLines[add = 0 and .5](O,A O,B)
    \tkzDrawArc[rotate,color=red](O,A)(180)
    \tkzDrawPoints(O,A,B)
    \tkzLabelPoints[below](O,A,B)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I get the same error message, and when I add to preamble `\usetkzobj{all}`, I get:
`undefined control sequence`
`<recently read>\usetkzobj`
Pressing Enter, I get: `LaTeX error: missing \begin{document}`

This happen me with all tex file with tkz-euclid package

Comment: @G.Aguilera Either your version of `tkz-euclide` is too old (I have used `2011/06/01 1.16 c`) or your installation is broken. Check the `.log` file, which files are found at which location.

Comment: I have the some version (`2011/06/01 1.16 c`). According to what the .log, the package files are in my texmf folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tkz-euclide`

Comment: @G.Aguilera `\usetkzobj` is defined in `latex/tkz-base/tkz-tools-utilities.tex`, same version.

Comment: In my localtexmf had a old folder with `tkz-2d.sty`. I delete this file, and problem solved!