# Error in compilation in a foreach loop in TikZ Euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tkz-euclide

Why the following document does not compile correctly? I would like an output drawing `n` consecutive semicircles. For `n=4` an output like this:

[image]

Is there a way to fix my code?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\def \n{4}
\foreach \i in {0,...,\n}
  {
  \tkzDefPoint(2*\i/\n,0){t_\i}
  \tkzDrawPoint(t_\i)
  }

\foreach \i in {0,...,\n/2}
{
\tkzDrawArc(t_(2*\i+1),t_(2*\i+2))(t_(2*\i))
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is a manual solution without `foreach`:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){A0}
\tkzDefPoint(.25,0){B0}
\tkzDefPoint(.5,0){A1}  
\tkzDefPoint(.75,0){B1}  
\tkzDefPoint(1,0){A2}  
\tkzDefPoint(1.25,0){B2}  
\tkzDefPoint(1.5,0){A3}  
\tkzDefPoint(1.75,0){B3}  
\tkzDefPoint(2,0){A4}  
\tkzDrawSegments(A0,A4)
\tkzDrawArc(B0,A1)(A0)
\tkzDrawArc(B1,A2)(A1)
\tkzDrawArc(B2,A3)(A2)
\tkzDrawArc(B3,A4)(A3)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Two problems. First is solved in https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133307/undefined-control-sequence-tkzdrawarc, you need to load `\usetkzobj{all}`. The second is about parameters for the arc, they are names of points (`t_0`) and you use operations which are not converted into names.

Comment: @Ignasi You marked this question as duplicate. I look at the question you linked. They say to add `\usetkzobj{all}`. But even after adding it I get the same error. I guess there is a syntax error in my code.

Comment: Yes, I was too fast. Excuse me. I've reopened it.

Comment: @Ignasi please do not hesitate to post an answer if you know how to fix the operations in the indices.

Comment: I am trying to write an answer... Can you give a manual representation first without the foreach of what exactly you want to do? Because the logic I think in the foreach is missing something. After all, you are defining points from 0 to 4, but in the \foreach, you would need points 5 and 6 as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple things that were wrong.

1. The error that it gives you is that the command `tkzDrawArc` is not defined. This usually means that there is some library that hasn't been loaded. Indeed, you were missing writing `\usetkzobj{all}`, that loads all the commands form the packages.
2. When you write `\n/2`, it is not doing what you think.

   The `\foreach` command can be written using the `/`, which has a special meaning...

   For our intents and purposes with regards to this question, we will just say that you can't do math operations in the foreach command itself, you have to do the math before you place the result on the foreach structure.

   Therefore, we will do them outside of the `\foreach` with a `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` command and later we will use that macro inside our `\foreach`.

   ```
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nhalf{\n/2}
   ...
   \foreach {1, ..., \nhalf}
   ```
3. Parenthesis don't collapse down to a name doing math. Hence, when you write  `t_(2*\i+1)`, it collapses to `t_(2*0+1)`, which is not a name you have defined (You have defined `t_1`. Each character is taken as part of the name).

   Which means that we have to use the same trick again. We calculate the value separately, and then we use it.

   ```
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\first}{(2*\i)}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{(2*\i+1)}
   \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\last}{2*\i-1}
   \tkzDrawArc(t_\first,t_\second)(t_\last)
   ```
4. There is a logical error: In your example, The last point that is needed to follow your logic would be `t_6`, and you have only defined up to `t_4` in the first `\foreach`. In the spirit of modifying only minimally your initial intent, I will only add points up to `t_6`.

With all that in mind, this is what you get to remove those errors (I took the liberty to add a `\tkzDrawLines` command and remove the `\tkzDrawPoint` to resemble better the picture that you post as an example):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\n{6}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\nhalf{\n/2-1}
    \foreach \i in {0,...,\n}{
      \tkzDefPoint(2*\i/\n,0){t_\i}
      %\tkzDrawPoint(t_\i) % Commented out, since in your drawing there are lines, not points drawn
    };
    \tkzDrawLines(t_0,t_\n) % Drawing the line like you show in your picture


    \foreach \i in {0,...,\nhalf}
    {
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\first}{(2*\i+1)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\second}{(2*\i+2)}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\last}{2*\i}
    \tkzDrawArc(t_\first,t_\second)(t_\last)

    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Solution]

Comment: Notice how `\n` is the number of points, the number of arcs that you are drawing in this way is `\n/2`

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. I will check it. I also provided a manual solution without `foreach` in my original question.

Comment: I confirm that your solution works perfect. The only change to obtain the exact picture is to change `tkzDrawLines` with `\tkzDrawSegments`. Thank you again.

Comment: In the next version, it's possible to draw directly a semi-circle

Comment: Alain. Do you mind giving which version number allows drawing a semi-circle? In case someone finds this on the future, where "next version" might not have the same meaning anymore

Answer (score 4):

Alex Recuenco already explained all errors that your code contains regarding use of `tkz-euclide` and Artificial Stupidity provided a `pstricks` solution, therefore I just have to provide a pure `TikZ` solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \i in {0,2,4,6}
\draw (\i,0) arc[start angle=180, end angle=0, radius=1cm];
\draw (0,0) -- (8,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to get the same output regardless of the implementation details, the following is a PSTricks solution.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\def\N{4}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(\N,.5)
    \multips(0,0)(1,0){\N}{\pscustom{\psarc(.5,0){.5}{0}{180}\closepath}}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]