# Drawing a picture in texmaker showing decorations errors

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

Here is the code that I want to use in Tex Maker.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    black,
    ultra thick,
    planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner,inner },
    circle label/.style = {
        postaction={
            decoration={
                text along path,
                text = {#1},
                text align=center,
                text color=black,
                reverse path,
            },
        decorate,
    }
    }
]
\filldraw[white] (-7,-7) rectangle (9,7);
 {\path[circle label={Abelian}] (0,-2.1) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (1);}
{\path[circle label={Nilpotent}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (2);}
{\path[circle label={O-group}] (0,-0.1) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);}
{\path[circle label={RO-group}] (0,+0.9) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (4);}
{\path[circle label={u.p.-group}] (0,+1.85) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (5);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But it shows me errors that

```
pgfkeys do not know the key decorations.
```

What else will I need to do?

Comment: Have you tried to use `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}`?

Comment: Most of packages loaded in your preamble are superfluous for this MWE. You only need to include `TiKZ`. `epsfig` is obsolete, even more if you load `graphicx`.

Comment: @they it was a part of my report. I anyways included them.

Comment: Then it might be an idea to revise the report/template ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't remember when, but `decorations` library was divided in several libraries, 
`text along path` belongs to `decorations.text` library

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    black,
    ultra thick,
    planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner,inner },
    circle label/.style = {
        postaction={
            decoration={
                text along path,
                text = {#1},
                text align=center,
                text color=black,
                reverse path,
            },
        decorate,
    }
    }
]
\filldraw[white] (-7,-7) rectangle (9,7);
 {\path[circle label={Abelian}] (0,-2.1) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (1);}
{\path[circle label={Nilpotent}] (0,-1.2) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (2);}
{\path[circle label={O-group}] (0,-0.1) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);}
{\path[circle label={RO-group}] (0,+0.9) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (4);}
{\path[circle label={u.p.-group}] (0,+1.85) arc (-90:360-90:1.2);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (5);}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

EDIT: If you want that labels follow inner circles, I propose to change the code to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    black,
    ultra thick,
    planet/.style = {draw,fill,circle,inner,inner },
    circle label/.style = {
        postaction={
            decoration={
                text along path,
                text = {#1},
                text align=center,
                text color=black,
                reverse path,
            },
        decorate,
    }
    }
]

\path[circle label={Abelian}] (0:1.1) arc (0:180:1.1);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (1);

\path[circle label={Nilpotent}] (0:2.1) arc (0:180:2.1);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (2);

\path[circle label={O-group}] (0:3.1) arc (0:180:3.1);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);

\path[circle label={RO-group}] (0:4.1) arc (0:180:4.1);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (4);

\path[circle label={u.p.-group}] (0:5.1) arc (0:180:5.1);
\draw[circle] (0,0) circle (5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Any idea why the text labels are not really following the curvature of the circles?

Comment: @daleif Yes, I just copied original code and replaced `decorations` by `decorations.text`. OP's code defined all labels over arcs with similar radius and not adjusted to corresponding circle. Now I've changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Just as addition to Ignasi I made a version which sets the labels on real arc-parts of the intermediate circles. Credits go to [cmhughes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66220) and Tom Bombadil!

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc}
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){ \path[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }

\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
        ,ultra thick
        ,circle label/.style = {%
            postaction={%
                ,decoration={%
                    ,text along path,
                    ,text = {#1},
                    ,text align=center,
                    ,reverse path,
                    }
                ,decorate
                }
            }
        ]
    \filldraw[white] (-7,-7) rectangle (9,7);
    {\centerarc[circle label={Abelian}](0,0)(0:180:.5)
        \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (1);}
    {\centerarc[circle label={Nilpotent}](0,0)(0:180:1.5)
        \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (2);}
    {\centerarc[circle label={O-group}](0,0)(0:180:2.5)
        \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (3);}
    {\centerarc[circle label={RO-group}](0,0)(0:180:3.5)
        \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (4);}
    {\centerarc[circle label={u.p.-group}](0,0)(0:180:4.5)
        \draw[circle] (0,0) circle (5);}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. It looks a lot better. I tried but could not get it right

Comment: You were a little bit faster than me. My update also solves this problem, but your solution is automatic.

Comment: @Ignasi "Talent imitates, genius steals" :-) Luckily, you got the accepted answer. I had no idea about that `decorations.text` before...