# Where to define new TikZ commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros

I have to start by saying that I am a newbie to LaTeX, let alone TikZ.

In order to solve another problem, I found a solution in another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/draw-arc-in-tikz-when-center-of-circle-is-specified) in a comment by Tom Bombadil. He defines the new command:

```
    \def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% 
[draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius) { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
```

This basically draws an arc with a given circle centre, initial and final angle. Now I am not sure about where I should define the command. I tried at the beginning of the Tikz picture, but it does not work.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,>=latex]
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% 
[draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius) { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); };
\centerarc[red, thick](0,0)(5:85:1);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Code in comments is badly formatted: the correct input should be

```
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
  { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
```

because the bits after the `%` are just comments showing the syntax.

You should have this in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) and probably you should also add a `\newcommand` just to be sure `\def` doesn't overwrite an existing command.

```
\newcommand\centerarc{} % just for safety
\def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5){%
  % Synopsis
  % \centerarc[draw options](center)(initial angle:final angle:radius)
  \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5);
}
```

Comment: Wow, I always was wondering if there isn't a way to combine the best of both (`\def` and `\newcommand`). Now seeing this, it looks so easy, yet it never crossed my mind to do it this way. Thanks a lot, I learned something new today!

Answer (score 4):

You could use extra `#n` to add flexibility. `[#1]#2(#3)#4(#5:#6:#7)` instead of `[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)`.

```
\def\centerarc[#1]#2(#3)#4(#5:#6:#7)% [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
  {\draw[#1]($(#3)+({#7*cos(#5)},{#7*sin(#5)})$)arc(#5:#6:#7);}
```

and then you can use

```
\centerarc[thick] (1,2) (10:20:1); % which has spaces for readability
```

You could probably use the power of `xparse` too, but I'm not sure about spaces since at this moment it doesn't accept spaces before certain arguments.

Comment: Wouldn't that also accept (unwanted) usage like `\centerarc[thick] Foo (1,2) Bar (10:20:1)`?

Comment: @quinmars Yes, but that's a side effect. Why would yo use that?

Comment: Shouldn't you replace `\centerarc[thick] (1,2) (10:20:1);` by `\centerarc[thick] (1,2) (10:20:1)` (no final semi column) for proper compilation?

Comment: I think in TikZ extra `;` do no harm. But may be I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You should define your new command outside, i.e. before the `tikzpicture` environment where you want to use it.

Comment: Using `\newcommand` is impossible for that case.

Comment: @egreg, OK, I realized that later and edited consequently my answer