# How can I get these instructions to work for drawing an arc with specified center?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Like many people I want to draw an arc of a circle with given center and given angles.  There are many questions about this on this site with accepted answers and I tried to cut and paste the clearest one.  That seems to  be the collaboration by cmhughes and Tom Bombadil at

[Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/draw-arc-in-tikz-when-center-of-circle-is-specified)

However it is not entirely explicit and I am evidently not putting the lines of code where they belong.  I tried

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \def\centerarc[#1](#2)(#3:#4:#5)% Syntax: [draw options] (center) (initial angle:final angle:radius)
    { \draw[#1] ($(#2)+({#5*cos(#3)},{#5*sin(#3)})$) arc (#3:#4:#5); }
   \centerarc[red,thick](0,0)(5:85:1)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And I get message : "See the tikz package documentation for explanation."  I did what I could with the documentation, and of course tried changing the code in many ways but did not hit on the right one.

Where do the lines belong?

Comment: You need to add tikz  `calc` library

Comment: If that is all you see of the error, then you are done a disservice by your editor. Look in the `.log` file, and you'll see that it says quite explicitly what you need to do: *"! Package tikz Error: You need to say `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` for coordinate calculation. See the tikz package documentation for explanation."*