# How draw this figure (spiral) in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

[image]

I would like to draw this figure in tikz. This figure below is already in tikz, but I would like to develop the code.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Please show us what code you have so far and be precise about where you have problems.

Comment: If you know that diagram was created with TikZ, have you tried asking whoever made it if you can see the code?

Answer (score 12):

Welcome to TeX.SE! Since this is your first question, here is some attempt to answer it. Please consider posting what you have tried in the future. (**EDIT**: closed the gaps and added the two missing annotations, thanks to Werner for reminding me.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{midmark/.style n args={2}{postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\node[font=\tiny] at (0,#2) {#1};}}}}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={R(\x)=0.3+\x/360;}]
\draw[line width=5mm,green] 
node[below right,black,xshift=-3mm,yshift=6mm]{AVA}
plot[variable=\x,domain=65:321] (\x:{R(\x)})
node[above left,black,xshift=2mm,yshift=-2mm]{FVA};
\draw[line width=5mm,orange] plot[variable=\x,domain=320:452,samples=31] (\x:{R(\x)});
\draw[line width=5mm,red] plot[variable=\x,domain=450:551,samples=61] (\x:{R(\x)})
node[black,left]{AVE};
\draw[line width=5mm,blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=550:830,samples=71] (\x:{R(\x)})
node[black,left,yshift=2.5mm,xshift=2mm]{FVE};
%
\draw[thin,<->,midmark={$25^\circ$}{-5pt}] plot[variable=\x,domain=65:90] (\x:{R(\x)+0.2});
\draw[thin,<->,midmark={$50^\circ$}{5pt}] plot[variable=\x,domain=270:320] (\x:{R(\x)+0.2});
\draw[white,thin,<->,midmark={$80^\circ$}{7pt}] plot[variable=\x,domain=550:630] (\x:{R(\x)+0.2});
\draw[white,thin,<->,midmark={$20^\circ$}{-5pt}] plot[variable=\x,domain=810:830] (\x:{R(\x)-0.2});
%
\draw (0,-pi) node[below] {PMI} -- (0,pi) node[above] {PMS};
%
\end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome as usual :)

Comment: How can one close the connections between the coloured segments?

Comment: @Werner By just adding 0.5 to the upper ends of all but the last domains or by increasing the numbers of samples or dialing `smooth`. As you probably know, plot (without the smooth option) just connects the points (whose number is given by `samples`) by straight lines. This is why the gaps arise: the slopes of the last segment of a plot and the first segment of the next plot do not coincide.

Answer (score 12):

### Edit: explanation of the method used to determine the nature of the spiral.

This curve is a spiral with two centers.

To determine this, I printed your image (my **printer** did not respect the original colors) then actually built with a ruler and compass the perpendicular bisector of the segment that cuts the small green curve on the left.

This allowed me to understand that this curve is a spiral with **2 centers**. To find the second centre, I extended the separation lines of the **green part** with the other two. I was able to see that the distance between the 2 centers is **5 mm**.

[image: printed-spiral]

It is constructed by drawing arcs of circles whose centre is alternately `R` and `L` which are 5mm apart.

[image: spirale-construction]

According to my measurements, the first circle has a radius of 5mm and therefore each of the others increases by 5mm.

First I built it this way with a line of normal thickness `L` and `R` are the centers of the arcs of the circle
: 
[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [every node/.style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt},
    >={Straight Barb[inset=3pt,angle=90:3pt]}]
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=.2mm](0,1)arc(90:65:5mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=.2mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=.2mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
\draw[draw=orange,line width=.2mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=.2mm](0,2)arc(90:190:20mm)coordinate(b);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=.2mm](b)arc(-170:-90:20mm)coordinate(c);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=.2mm](c)arc(-90:90:25mm)coordinate(d);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=.2mm](d)arc(90:110:30mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To build this spiral, it is therefore necessary to build arcs of a given center circle. Here to avoid having to recalculate these centers, I have named the points where the spiral ends `(a)`, `(b)`, `(c)` and `(d)`.

To draw the arrows, I had to draw arcs of circles of known center and to do so, I used the technique indicated by @JonathanGratus in his answer here:  [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453649/138900) like this:

`\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)`

And finally, I placed the text separately.

[image: spiral-final]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [every node/.style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt},
    >={Straight Barb[inset=3pt,angle=90:3pt]}]
%\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
%\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:65:5mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=6mm](0,2)arc(90:190:20mm)coordinate(b);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](b)arc(-170:-90:20mm)coordinate(c);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](c)arc(-90:90:25mm)coordinate(d);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](d)arc(90:110:30mm);

% arrows placement 
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/453649/138900
\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(190:22mm)arc(190:270:22mm)node[midway,above right,inner sep=0pt]{$80^\circ$};
\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(90:28mm)arc(90:110:28mm)node[midway,above,inner sep=1pt]{$20^\circ$};

% node placement 
\node[anchor=north west] at ([shift={(-.1,.5)}]65:2mm){AVA};
\node[above left]at([shift={(-5pt,5pt)}]a){FVA};
\node[anchor=east]at(190:23mm){AVE};
\draw[node font=\bf](0,-3)node[below]{PMI}--(0,4)node[above]{PMS};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit : Just for fun, an animation that builds this spiral.

its code is not optimized.

[image: spirale-animation]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}


%\begin{tikzpicture}
%\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
%\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
%\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};
%\end{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{every node/.style={font=\footnotesize,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=1pt},>={Straight Barb[inset=3pt,angle=90:3pt]}}
\foreach \a in {-90,-85,...,65}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};
\draw(0,5mm)--([shift={(0,5mm)}]\a:8mm);
%\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:\a:5mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}

}

\foreach \a in {70,75,...,90}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};
\draw(0,5mm)--([shift={(0,5mm)}]\a:8mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:\a:5mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {95,100,...,270}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw(0,0)--(\a:13mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:\a:10mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {275,280,...,320}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw(0,5mm)--([shift={(0,5mm)}]\a:18mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:\a:15mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {-35,-30,...,90}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
%\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw(0,.5)--([shift={(0,5mm)}]\a:18mm);
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:\a:15mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {95,100,...,190}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
%\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=6mm](0,2)arc(90:\a:20mm)coordinate(b);
\draw(0,0)--(\a:23mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {-165,-160,...,-90}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
%\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=6mm](0,2)arc(90:190:20mm)coordinate(b);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](b)arc(-170:\a:20mm)coordinate(c);
\draw(0,0)--(\a:23mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {-85,-80,...,90}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
%\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=6mm](0,2)arc(90:190:20mm)coordinate(b);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](b)arc(-170:-90:20mm)coordinate(c);
%\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(190:22mm)arc(190:270:22mm)node[midway,above right,inner sep=0pt]{$80^\circ$};
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](c)arc(-90:\a:25mm)coordinate(d);
\draw(0,.5)--([shift={(0,5mm)}]\a:28mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {95,100,...,110}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
%\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=6mm](0,2)arc(90:190:20mm);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](b)arc(-170:-90:20mm)coordinate(c);
%\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(190:22mm)arc(190:270:22mm)node[midway,above right,inner sep=0pt]{$80^\circ$};
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](c)arc(-90:90:25mm)coordinate(d);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](d)arc(90:\a:30mm);
%\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(90:28mm)arc(90:110:28mm)node[midway,above,inner sep=1pt]{$20^\circ$};
\draw(0,0)--(\a:33mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\foreach \a in {115,120,...,270}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\useasboundingbox(-2.5,-2.5)rectangle(3,3.5);
\fill[green!50!black](0,0)circle(1pt)node[left]{L};
\fill[green!50!black](0,5mm)circle(1pt)node[left]{R};

\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,5mm)+(65:5mm)arc(65:90:5mm);
%\draw[<->] (0,.5)+(65:7mm) arc (65:90:7mm)node[shift={(9pt,6pt)}]{$25^\circ$};
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,1)arc(90:270:10mm);
\draw[draw=green,line width=6mm](0,-1)arc(270:320:15mm)coordinate(a);
%\draw[<->](0,.5)+(-90:17mm)arc(-90:-40:17mm)node[midway,above]{$50^\circ$};
\draw[draw=orange,line width=6mm](a)arc(-40:90:15mm);
\draw[draw=red,line width=6mm](0,2)arc(90:190:20mm);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](b)arc(-170:-90:20mm)coordinate(c);
%\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(190:22mm)arc(190:270:22mm)node[midway,above right,inner sep=0pt]{$80^\circ$};
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](c)arc(-90:90:25mm)coordinate(d);
\draw[draw=blue,line width=6mm](d)arc(90:110:30mm);
%\draw[<->,white](0,0)+(90:28mm)arc(90:110:28mm);%node[midway,above,inner sep=1pt]{$20^\circ$};
\draw(0,0)--(\a:33mm);
\draw(0,-3)--(0,3.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you change the title of the question? If so, how do you know that the OP wants a "spiral with two centers"?

Comment: @marmot Yes, I changed the title of the question because this curve is really a two-center spiral. To verify this, I printed the image attached by the OP and checked with a compass and a ruler by drawing mediators, which allowed me to verify the nature of this curve as well as its construction.

Comment: Are you saying that my proposal does not match? (To me the results look almost identical.) I would actually refrain from making such drastic edits to questions without consulting the OP first.

Comment: @marmot I had not noticed that your solution did not correspond, I was convinced that you had also made a spiral with two centres without having taken the trouble to check, I am confused. I voted for your solution because it taught me a lot of things I didn't know yet.

Comment: I believe that my solution (also) reproduces the OP's screen shot. I am not saying yours does not, but I am not sure if your construction mechanism is advantageous or precisely what the OP wants. Rather, I really believe one should consult the OP for that.

Comment: @marmot The green curve to the left of the vertical line is a semi-circle. There are many different spirals in geometry, yours is very beautiful and I really like the way you built it. I have deleted the mention `with two centres` from the title.

Comment: Thanks! +1. (I am not saying that you are not right, but I'd let the OP decide.)