# A defined macro works with \draw but not with \fill

Tags: tikz-pgf, arc

I used the `\centerarc` command provided in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66220/50293) answer to fill a region enclosed by arcs. I have made a slight modification. I have removed the `\draw` inside the definition and the first parameter.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\centerarc(#1)(#2:#3:#4){ ($(#1)+({#4*cos(#2)},{#4*sin(#2)})$) arc (#2:#3:#4); }
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (1.6,0);
    \coordinate (C) at (4,-2.5);

    \draw \centerarc(0,0)(48.23:60:1.6);
    \draw \centerarc(1.6,0)(120:180:1.6);   
    \draw \centerarc(4,-2.5)(128.47:147.99:4.72);
    \fill[red]\centerarc(0,0)(48.23:60:1.6) -- \centerarc(1.6,0)(120:180:1.6) -- \centerarc(4,-2.5)(128.47:147.99:4.72);


    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The command `\centerarc` works perfectly when I use `\draw`. But when I try to use `\fill`, it just prints the command as text.

Why is this happening and is there a workaround?

Comment: Remove the `;` at the end of the definition of `\centerarc`. It's closing the path prematurely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\draw` commands work because this:

```
\draw \centerarc(0,0)(48.23:60:1.6);
```

expands to this:

```
\draw ($(0,0)+({1.6*cos(48.23)},{1.6*sin(48.23)})$) arc (48.23:60:1.6);;
```

(with a duplicated `;` at the end, which won't harm).

But this (replacing the first command only):

```
\fill[red] \centerarc(0,0)(48.23:60:1.6) -- \centerarc(1.6,0)(120:180:1.6) -- \centerarc(4,-2.5)(128.47:147.99:4.72);
```

becomes (line break added for clarity):

```
\fill[red] ($(#1)+({#4*cos(#2)},{#4*sin(#2)})$) arc (#2:#3:#4);
  -- \centerarc(1.6,0)(120:180:1.6) -- \centerarc(4,-2.5)(128.47:147.99:4.72);
```

which ends the `\fill` instruction at the `;`.

The remaining `-- \centerarc\ETC.` shouldn't cause any trouble (except not working as one would expect), except that Ti*k*Z ignores stray *text* in a `tikzpicture` environment, but not math. So everything between `$`...`$` in the definition of `\centerarc` is written to the PDF.

Solution: remove the `;` in the definition :)

```
\def\centerarc(#1)(#2:#3:#4){ ($(#1)+({#4*cos(#2)},{#4*sin(#2)})$) arc (#2:#3:#4) }
```