# How does TikZ render an arc?

Tags: tikz-pgf

With the sample MWE below, TikZ generates the following diagram:

**1. Drawing an arc**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=below:$a$] (a) at (0,0);

  \draw (a) arc(0:180:2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**2. Drawing a circle**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=below:$a$] (a) at (0,0);
  \coordinate[label=below:$b$] (b) at (5,5);

  \draw (a) arc(0:180:2);
  \draw (b) circle [radius=2cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\draw <coordinate> circle` command, TikZ draws a circle, with the `<coordinate>` at its center.

With `\draw <coordinate> arc` command, TikZ draws an arc, with the `<coordinate>` as one of its endpoints.

I wish to understand, why this difference of behavior and how is TikZ drawing the arc with `\draw (a) arc(0:180:2);`.

Why does TikZ does not use `(a)` as its center point while drawing an arc similar to drawing a circle.

How does TikZ actually draw the arc with point `a`.

What is the reference and center point, when TikZ draws an arc.

Comment: May I draw your attention to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66216/121799)? IMHO the question "Why does Ti*k*Z does not use `(a)` as its center point while drawing an arc similar to drawing a circle?" is not really answerable, and there are more than enough answers that show you how you can get whatever behavior you want.

Comment: @marmot that doesn't actually answer the question. I want to understand the mathematical geometry behind the example given

Comment: The mathematical geometry of an arc and a circle? Judging from the question you seem to understand it very well. (Internally Ti*k*Z approximates them with Bezier curves, if that's your question.)

Comment: What is the geometry here? It is just simply the beginning angle and the ending angle.

Comment: @marmot - When we draw an arc on a paper, we need a compass, a center point and radius. That is one of the ways (mathematically) to draw an arc. In that case, center and reference points are the same. I am trying to map that logic in TikZ (in my last question).

Comment: The logic is very simple: consider `\draw (x,y) arc(alpha:beta:r);` Now draw a circle of radius `r` such that `(x,y)` is at the position specified by the angle `alpha`, Now Ti*k*Z draws an arc from that point to the point with angle `beta` along that circle.

Comment: @marmot I just had a look at `tikz.code.tex`, in the `arc` part. It told me that `(The syntax with parentheses is deprecated.)`. Ohh I have been wrong for so long

Comment: @JouleV Yes, but there is a difference between really deprecated and "if you do this, do not blame the developers of Ti*k*Z for possible side-effects". AFAIK you will only see real problems if you use more complicated coordinate systems.

Comment: @marmot Yes, but I have to "update" myself right now

Comment: @marmot - Can you please detail the comment as an answer.

Comment: @subhamsoni Go to [`pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex`](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/master/tex/generic/pgf/basiclayer/pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex), line 363. You can see a comment about a Bezier curve inside an arc construct command. That may answer your question

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here is an attempt to use an animation to explain step by step what's going on. I use the non-deprecated syntax, as suggested by Joule V.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{The arc construction}
\textbackslash\texttt{draw (P) arc[start angle=$\alpha$,end 
angle=$\beta$,radius=$r$];}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt,label=right:{$P=(x,y)$}] (P){};
 \draw[dashed,visible on=<2-3>] (P) ++ (210:2) coordinate (O) circle[radius=2cm];
 \draw[visible on=<2>] (O) + (1,0) arc[start angle=00,end angle=30,radius=1cm] 
 node[midway,right] {$\alpha$};
 \draw[visible on=<2>] (P) -- (O) -- ++(2,0) node[midway,below]{$r$};
 \draw[visible on=<3-4>,thick] (P) arc[start angle=30,end angle=135,radius=2cm]
 coordinate (Q);
 \draw[visible on=<3>] (O) + (1,0) arc[start angle=00,end angle=135,radius=1cm] 
 node[midway,below] {$\beta$} (Q) -- (O) -- ++(2,0) ;
 \path (O) -- ++ (0,2.5); % only for the bounding box
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{itemize}
 \item<+-> Consider a point $P=(x,y)$.
 \item<+-> Imagine now a circle of radius $r$ for which $P$ sits at the angle
 $\alpha$.
 \item<+-> The arc runs along this circle between the angles $\alpha$ and
 $\beta$.
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, very clear!

Comment: Amazing. I'm getting `No file tikz-arcs.nav.` attempting to run the code. Some library I need to install?

Comment: The shorter synatx is not "deprecated" to my knowledge.

Answer (score 7):

Short answer: `arc` has nothing to do with `circle`. `circle` is drawn with four curves, `arc` is drawn with one curve, that is all.

Let's start with `tikz.code.tex`. In lines 3673–3706, there is the definition of `\tikz@do@arc`, based on `\pgfpatharc`, which is defined in `pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex`. Circles and ellipses are defined in the same way.

In `pgfcorepathconstruct.code.tex`, `\pgfpatharc` is defined as a curve with a starting point and an ending point, based on `\pgf@nlt@curveto` (line 401).

Meanwhile, you can see that any kind of curves, even circles, are defined based on `\pgf@nlt@curveto`. Circles and ellipses is defined in `\pgfpathellipse` as a set of four connected curves: line 926, line 947, line 968, and line 989 — each of these curves has its own `\pgf@nlt@curveto`.

That is why the `arc` does not take its coordinate as the center, but a starting point.

Answer (score 2):

A PSTricks solution just for fun.

In PSTricks, drawing circular arcs as well as elliptical arcs is very intuitive as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[dimen=m](4,4)
    \pscircle[linestyle=dashed](2,2){2}
    \psellipse[linestyle=dashed](2,2)(2,1)
    \psarc[linecolor=red](2,2){2}{45}{90}
    \psellipticarc[linecolor=red,correctAngle=true](2,2)(2,1){45}{90}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This solution has made me fall in love with PSTricks. It is so cool