# Drawing arc with pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using pgf, I'd like to draw an arc (part of a circle) with a given center. I don't know the exact co-ordinates of the center, because it was obtained as an intersection of other geometric objects. The desired center has a name, but no known co-ordinates. How can I do this?

Basically, I'd like to modify an instruction of the form

```
 \node (H) [name path=H, draw, circle through=(A')] at (E) {};
```

to produce just a part of the circle.

Comment: You should provide a Minimal Working example starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` that provides all the minimal necessary commands and instructions to understand what you want. You should also specify which libraries you are loading and what are you doing.

Comment: I'm a bit unsure what's so hard to understand. I have points A' and E defined and would like to draw merely part of the circle through A' at E.

Comment: Of course, if you know the starting location and angle and radius (needed for arc with tikz), you can locate the center.  The problem is usually finding the angles.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66216/14500

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `arc` command of Ti*k*z, like so:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0); % Your coordinate name
    \draw (O) -- ++(0:1) arc (0:150:1); % start:end:radius
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which results in something like this

[image: arc]

In general your last command will be

```
\draw (center) -- ++(start:radius) arc(start:end:radius) -- (center);
```

Comment: That's great, but I'd just like the arc, without the two radii included.

Comment: `\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0); % Your coordinate name
    \draw (O)+(0:1) arc (0:150:1); % start:end:radius
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
`?

Answer (score 1):

I did not really understand the question. I assume you want to create a circular node centered on E, which goes through A but draw partially!

I suggest the solution below

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{through}
\usepackage{SIunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[label=A] (A)  at (1,1) {+};

\node[label=E] (E) at (0,2){+};

 \node (H) [name path=H, circle through=(A)] at (E) {}; 

\draw[red,thick]
let
 \p1=(E.center), \p2=(A), \n1={veclen(\y2-\y1,\x2-\y1)}
in
(H.45) arc (45:180: \n1);

\draw (H) -- ++(3,4);
\draw (H) -- ++(-3,5);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1) First of all if the center has a name then you can know its coordinates:

> 102.6 Extracting Coordinates There are two commands that can be used to “extract” the x- or y-coordinate of a coordinate.

`\pgfextractx{\pgf@x}{\pgfpointanchor{E}{center}}
 \pgfextracty{\pgf@y}{\pgfpointanchor{E}{center}}`

2) With `tkz-euclide`you have:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\begin{document} 

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate[label=$O$] (O) at (3,1);
  \coordinate [label=$A$](A) at (1,5);
  \coordinate [label=$B$](B) at (2,4);
  \coordinate [label=$C$](C) at (3,2);
  \coordinate [label=$D$](D) at (5,0);
  \coordinate [label=$E$](E) at (5,1);
  \tkzCompass[thick,blue](O,A) 
  \tkzCompass[thick,red,delta=20](O,B)
  \tkzCompass[thick,orange,length=2](O,C)
  \tkzDrawArc[thick,brown](O,D)(E)
  \foreach \point in {A,...,E,O}
  \fill [black,opacity=.5] (\point) circle (1pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

a) The macro `\tkzCompass` can draw an arc with a center through a point. Without option (you can use  TikZ's options) the arc has a length of 1 cm;

b) you can use the option `length` to change the default value `length =2 for 2cm`;

c) you can use the option `delta`. `delta=20` means that the ends of the arc makes an angle of 40 degrees with the center;

d) more subtle is the last possibility. With `\tkzDrawArc(O,D)(E)` you draw an arc with center O passing through `D` and stopping on the half line `[OE)`.

[image]