# How can I draw an arc centered at the center of a node

Tags: tikz-styles

I want to draw an arc centered at the center of a node (a), I have not been able to find how to draw te arc specifying its center as (a.center), the only option I found is either using cartesian or polar coordinates

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in [Draw arc in tikz when center of circle is specified](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66216/draw-arc-in-tikz-when-center-of-circle-is-specified)

parametrising the coordinates is ok