# Line between two nodes on a circle in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to connect two nodes n1 and n2 following a circle of a given radius. I tried to play with `to[bend left=<>]`, but it never fits perfectly (in the picture below I highlighted the problem). Any ideas?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\radius{2cm}
    \draw[color=black!50, name path=c] (0:\radius) arc (0:360:\radius);
    \node[draw, circle, fill=white, name path=n1] at (110:\radius) (n1) {n1}; 
    \node[draw, circle, fill=white, name path=n2] at (0:\radius) (n2) {n2}; 
    
    \path[name intersections={of=n1 and c, by={i1, i2}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=n2 and c, by={i2, i3}}];
    
    \node[draw, red, circle, scale=0.5] at (i1) {};
    \node[draw, red, circle, scale=0.5] at (i2) {};
    
    \draw[<-, >=latex, blue] (i1) to[bend left=41] (i2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: For figuring out the arc, you may find this question a useful starting point https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66216/86

Answer (score 1):

Using the `bending` library, and a value of 44 for the bending, this seems to fit.

[image: bend on a circle]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \def\radius{2cm}
    \draw[color=black!50, name path=c] (0:\radius) arc (0:360:\radius);
    \node[draw, circle, fill=white, name path=n1] at (110:\radius) (n1) {n1}; 
    \node[draw, circle, fill=white, name path=n2] at (0:\radius) (n2) {n2}; 
    
    \path[name intersections={of=n1 and c, by={i1, i2}}];
    \path[name intersections={of=n2 and c, by={i2, i3}}];
    
    \node[draw, red, circle, scale=0.5] at (i1) {};
    \node[draw, red, circle, scale=0.5] at (i2) {};
    
    \draw[<-, >=latex, blue] (i1) to[bend left=44] (i2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there are way to compute the bend value?

Comment: I'm not aware if there's a way to do it. Try and error did the trick here. But more important is the `bending` library, which allows your bended arrow to be correctly bended (like if there was no arrow tip).