# Hexagon commutative diagram in mathematics (Herbrand quotient diagram)

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

The following code

```
\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \def\radius{3cm} % change to an appropriate value
    \node (h0A) at (60:\radius)   {$H^0(G,A)$};
    \node (h0C) at (0:\radius)    {$H^0(G,C)$};
    \node (h1B) at (-60:\radius)  {$H^1(G,B)$};
    \node (h1A) at (-120:\radius) {$H^1(G,A)$};
    \node (h1C) at (180:\radius)  {$H^1(G,C)$};
    \node (h0B) at (120:\radius)  {$H^0(G,B)$};

    \path[->,font=\small]
        (h0A) edge node[auto] {$g_0$} (h0C)
        (h0C) edge node[auto] {$\delta_0$} (h1B)
        (h1B) edge node[auto] {$f_1$} (h1A)
        (h1A) edge node[auto] {$g_1$} (h1C)
        (h1C) edge node[auto] {$\delta_1$} (h0B)
        (h0B) edge node[auto] {$f_0$} (h0A);
\end{tikzpicture}\]
```

[image]

But I want to exchange `$A$` and `$B$` and write the following diagram.
But when I exchange `$A$` and `$B$` in the above diagram, diagram is destroyed.
How can I write the diagram below in LaTeX?

[image]

Comment: Provided that you load the `amssym` package (you should always post *complete* MWEs including `\documentclass` and all relevant packages), you can put `\node[rotate=180] at (0,0) {$\circlearrowright$};` to your document in order to typset the clockwise arrow in the center of your diagram.

Comment: @JasperHabicht - Great suggestion for the additional node; in fact, I've updated my answer to include [borrow?, steal??] your suggestion. (You're familiar with Picasso's saying in this regard, right?)

Comment: @Mico Oh, sure! It should be considered implemeting an inspiration, I guess. I'd say that coding is almost always largely based on copying ... =)

Answer (score 6):

(too long for a comment, hence posted as an answer; updated to include @JasperHabicht's suggestion)

I do not find that the "diagram is destroyed" when I replace the letter sequence A-C-B-A-C-B in the node list with B-C-A-B-C-A.

Note that it's not necessary to update the six node names in a similar fashion. In fact, it might be good idea to label the nodes *without reference* to their contents. E.g., one might choose `u`, `v`, `w`, `x`, `y`, and `z` as the six node names.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \def\radius{3.3cm} % choose an appropriate value
    \node (u) at ( 60:\radius) {$H^0(G,B)$};
    \node (v) at (  0:\radius) {$H^0(G,C)$};
    \node (w) at (300:\radius) {$H^1(G,A)$};
    \node (x) at (240:\radius) {$H^1(G,B)$};
    \node (y) at (180:\radius) {$H^1(G,C)$};
    \node (z) at (120:\radius) {$H^0(G,A)$};

    \path[->]
          (u) edge node[auto] {$g_0$}      (v)
          (v) edge node[auto] {$\delta_0$} (w)
          (w) edge node[auto] {$f_1$}      (x)
          (x) edge node[auto] {$g_1$}      (y)
          (y) edge node[auto] {$\delta_1$} (z)
          (z) edge node[auto] {$f_0$}      (u);

    \node[rotate=180] at (0,0) {\Huge$\circlearrowright$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

This is a job for `tikz-cd`.

I didn't use `\circlearrowright` because its tip is different from `-latex` one.
I drew a circle arrow, this way you can customize it as you wish (arrow tip, position, dimension).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}
\tikzcdset{
    arrow style=tikz,
    arrows={>={latex}},
}

\begin{document}
% code for centering the circle arrow taken from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66219/101651
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
  every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},
  execute at end picture={\draw[-{latex[flex']}]([shift=(230:6mm)]mycd.center) arc (230:-45:6mm);}
  ]
    &[-33pt] H^0(G,A)\ar[r,"f_0"] &[13pt] H^0(G,B)\ar[rd,"g_0"]&[-33pt]\\[40pt]
    H^1(G,C)\ar[ur,"\delta_1"] &&& H^0(G,C)\ar[ld,"\delta_0"]\\[40pt]
    & H^1(G,B)\ar[ul,"g_1"] & H^1(G,A)\ar[l,"f_1"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot compile it in my overleaf. Circle arrow should occurred error. How can I manage it ?

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction Did you add `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}` in your preamble?

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction Also the other definitions I put in my preamble.

Comment: @BrauerManinobstruction In Overleaf my code works, see here https://www.overleaf.com/read/thgbgpxxzkkx#025537

Answer (score 3):

Variation of nice @Mico answer (+1) with use of `quotes` library and drawn circle arrow in the middle of hexagon:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \[
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        >=latex,
everyy edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\fontsize}
                    ]
\def\radius{3.3cm} % choose an appropriate value
\node (n1) at (120:\radius) {$H^0(G,A)$};
\node (n2) at ( 60:\radius) {$H^0(G,B)$};
\node (n3) at (  0:\radius) {$H^0(G,C)$};
\node (n4) at (300:\radius) {$H^1(G,A)$};
\node (n5) at (240:\radius) {$H^1(G,B)$};
\node (n6) at (180:\radius) {$H^1(G,C)$};

\path[->]
      (n1) edge["$f_0$"]      (n2)
      (n2) edge["$g_0$"]      (n3)
      (n3) edge["$\delta_0$"] (n4)
      (n4) edge["$f_1$"]      (n5)
      (n5) edge["$g_1$"]      (n6)
      (n6) edge["$\delta_1$"] (n1);

\draw[->] (240:1.2) arc (240:-60:1.2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `chains`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {chains}

\newcommand{\radius}{3}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex, start chain=herbrand placed {at=(180-60*\tikzchaincount:\radius)}]
    \foreach \H in {{H^0(G,A)},{H^0(G,B)},{H^1(G,C)},{H^1(G,A)},{H^1(G,B)},{H^0(G,C)}}
        {\node [on chain] {$\H$};}
    \foreach \L[count=\n, evaluate=\n as \m using {int(mod(\n,6)+1)}] in {f_0,g_0,\delta_0,f_1,g_1,\delta_1}
        {\draw[->] (herbrand-\n) to[edge label=$\L$] (herbrand-\m);}
    \draw[->] (270:.5)arc(270:-45:.5);
\end{tikzpicture}\]

\end{document}
```